# Javascript: How to loop through array of objects for post request for array property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, axios

I have an `array` response and i need to pass post request data from that response. The response have nested array objects as well. So how to loop through those array objects into post api request key values ?

Response which i am getting is as below:

```
records = "data": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Black Panther",
    "product_images": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "images": {
          "id": 1,
          "thumbnail_image": "/assets/1/image.jpg",
        },
      }, 
      {
        "id": 2,
        "images": {
          "id": 2,
          "thumbnail_image": "/assets/2/image.jpg",
        },
      }
    ],
    product_categories: [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "categories": {
          "id": 3,
          "category_name": "Outdoor Sports"
        }
    }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now i need to pass that `product_images` array object's `images.thumbnail_image` property into the post request key value.

```
records.map((element) => {
  let data;  
  data = {
    "id": element.id,
    "name": element.title,
    "image_files":
      [
        {
          "url": "" // need to pass thumbnail_image value over here. 
        }
      ],
    "product_category": {
        "category_id": [1,2] // need to pass product_categories[i].categories.id value over here. 
    }
  }
})
```

axios post API request is as below:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'api_url',
  data: {
      "products": data,
  }
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
});
```

P.S: I have tried to manage this issue with loop through into the `image_files` array as below but that is working.

```
"image_files": [
element.product_images.map((ele) => {
  {
    "url": ele.images.thumbnail_image
  }
})
]
```

::Updated::

I also need to manage that category property into the post api request. I have tried like this way but it pass the `[null]` value

```
"category_id": lists.campaign_product_categories.map((element) => {
  let arr = []
  arr.push(element.categories.id)
}),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested `map` statement with destructuring to achieve this.

```js
let records = [ { "id": 1, "title": "Black Panther", "product_images": [ { "id": 1, "images": { "id": 1, "thumbnail_image": "/assets/1/image.jpg", }, }, { "id": 2, "images": { "id": 2, "thumbnail_image": "/assets/2/image.jpg", }, } ] } ];
let data = records.map(({id, title:name, product_images}) => (
  {
    id, name,
    "image_files": product_images.map(({images:{thumbnail_image: url}})=>({
      url  
    }))
  }
));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for your quick response. I am able to manage from your answer as well.

Comment: I have updated my question regarding `category` property and for that i have applied the same solution but that is not working in that case.

Comment: You need to use `return element.categories.id`, not push.

Answer (score 1):

You can just map the sub array for each array element like so:

```js
const records = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Black Panther",
    product_images: [
      {
        id: 1,
        images: {
          id: 1,
          thumbnail_image: "/assets/1/image.jpg",
        },
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        images: {
          id: 2,
          thumbnail_image: "/assets/2/image.jpg",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];

const mapped = records.map((element) => ({
  id: element.id,
  name: element.title,
  image_files: element.product_images.map((i) => ({
    url: i.images.thumbnail_image,
  })),
}));

console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this code snippet... It works for me and i am able to manage my dynamic data accordingly. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a map on the product images inner array to create the URL array

```js
let apiResponses = records.data.map((dataElement) => {
  
  let urls =  dataElement.product_images.map((product_image) => {
    return {"url": product_image.images.thumbnail_image}
  })
  return {
    "id": dataElement.id,
    "name": dataElement.title,
    "image_files":
      urls,  
  }
})
console.log(apiResponses[0])
```

Outputs

```js
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Black Panther',
  image_files: [ { url: '/assets/1/image.jpg' }, { url: '/assets/2/image.jpg' } ]
}
```

Full code below

```js
let records = {"data": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Black Panther",
    "product_images": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "images": {
          "id": 1,
          "thumbnail_image": "/assets/1/image.jpg",
        },
      }, 
      {
        "id": 2,
        "images": {
          "id": 2,
          "thumbnail_image": "/assets/2/image.jpg",
        },
      }
    ]
  }
]}

let apiResponses = records.data.map((dataElement) => {
  
  let urls =  dataElement.product_images.map((product_image) => {
    return {"url": product_image.images.thumbnail_image}
  })
  return {
    "id": dataElement.id,
    "name": dataElement.title,
    "image_files":
      urls,  
  }
})
console.log(apiResponses[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the return statement

```
records.map((element) => {
  let data;  
  data = {
    "id": element.id,
    "name": element.title,
    "image_files":
      [
        {
          "url": "" // need to pass thumbnail_image value over here. 
        }
      ],  
  }
  return data; // <------- this line
})
```